# Help me identifying this japanese font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, style-identification, font-design

Can someone help me identifying this japanese font?

[image: text image]

I have tried font identification site like [likefont](https://likefont.com) but still haven't found the exact same one.

This image is from a T-Shirt image, and this is the only image I have. I have tried clean it a bit and make it black and white for make it easier for Font ID.

[image: cleaned image]

Comment: Check [this](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions) out for what else is expected when asking about finding a font. This would be easier for us to help, too.

Comment: That image is not good enough quality for automated font ID sites. Either find a better image or try to clean it up a bit first.  TBH it looks like it might not even be a font. It could have been hand drawn. Not everything is a font you can download.

Comment: Also, the sample is rather too small to really say for sure; none of the glyphs contain curved strokes which would help identify the style. But quick googling for katakana fonts got me https://www.kanjisensei.com/japanesefonts/katakanafonts.html which has a few gothic ones which could perhaps be worth looking at, though nothing obviously similar. For what it's worth, the text seems to be オヤスミュギタ though I'm really unsure about the last one. (I don't read Japanese.)